# Error "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" when using difftime

Tags: r, datetime, datediff

I'm calculate the difference in seconds of two consecutive row with the following code

```
set.seed(79)

library(outbreaks)
library(lubridate)

# Import data
disease_df <- measles_hagelloch_1861[, 3, drop = FALSE]

# Generate a random time for each day
disease_df$time <- sample(1:86400, nrow(disease_df), replace = TRUE)
disease_df$time <- hms::as.hms(disease_df$time)

# Combine date and time
disease_df$time1 <- with(disease_df, ymd(date_of_prodrome) + hms(time))

# Sort data
disease_df <- disease_df[order(disease_df$time1), ]

# Difference in days of two consecutive row
disease_df$diff <- as.numeric(difftime(disease_df$date_of_prodrome,
                                       dplyr::lag(disease_df$date_of_prodrome, 1), units = 'days'))

# Difference in seconds of two consecutive row
disease_df$diff1 <- as.numeric(difftime(disease_df$time1,
                                       dplyr::lag(disease_df$time1, 1), units = 'secs'))
```

Here is the resulted dataframe

[image]

and error message `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`.

Could you please explain why `difftime` works fine for days but results in error for seconds? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time1` column is of type `"POSIXlt"`. I am not really sure why `difftime` with `units = 'secs'` doesn't work but if you convert it to `POSIXct`, it works without any error.

```
disease_df$time1 <- as.POSIXct(disease_df$time1)
disease_df$diff1 <- as.numeric(difftime(disease_df$time1,
                               dplyr::lag(disease_df$time1, 1), units = 'secs'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `dplyr` was not happy wth the line: `dplyr::lag(disease_df$time1, 1)` because of the format of `disease_df$time1`.

Converting it to POSIXct works, so just update this part of your code:

```
# Combine date and time and convert to POSIXct
disease_df$time1 <- as.POSIXct(with(disease_df, ymd(date_of_prodrome) + hms(time)))
```